# How to check if DropdownButton has a selected value?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I check if there is a selected ìtem in my `DropdownButton` before I press a `Button` and `Toast` a error message if no item is selected?

I have been searching for a solution but no hope yet.
I am checking if all my `TextField` is empty, and that works. But haven't found any solution for the `DropdownButton`. The `ElevatedButton` saves the data to firebase.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
child: DropdownButtonFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)
              ),

            ),
            items: _isAdmin
                .map((value) => DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text(
                value,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              value: value,
            ))
                .toList(),
            onChanged: (selectedadmin){
              setState(() {
                isadmin = selectedadmin;

              });
            },
            value: isadmin,
            isExpanded: false,
            elevation: 10,

          ),
        ),


        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              var Name = nameController.text.trim();
              var email = emailController.text.trim();
              var password = passwordController.text.trim();
              var mobilenumber = mobileController.text.trim();
              var empid = employeidController.text.trim();



              if (Name.isEmpty ||
                  email.isEmpty ||
                  password.isEmpty ||
                  empid.isEmpty ||
                  mobilenumber.isEmpty) {
                // show error toast
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike TextFormField, DropdownButtonFormField doesn't have a controller. However you have the `onChange` method, where you are setting the isadmin variable. You should check the value of the `isadmin` var within the `onPressed` in your button.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I have tried many ways inside my `onPressed` function. But still nothing. My `List` is this `_isAdmin` and that holds two items. But if I am going to use `isEmpty` I have to do this with my `_isAdmin` and not `isadmin`. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Your List `_isAdmin` is different than the variable `isadmin` that holds the selected item when `onChange`. I assume that you declared `isadmin` as `String?` (nullable), so in your onPressed method you should have something like: `if(isadmin == null) { // Error toast }`

Comment: I did manage to find a solution, thanks!